# Adding a scheduled build to the build configuration

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm currently working on a script that changes some configuration on a build definition. One of these changes is to add a trigger that schedules a build to run every weekday at 2 am.

My approach was to manually add the trigger first and then reproduce it with API calls. The configuration leads to the following in the build definition:

```
"triggers": [
    {
        "schedules": [
            {
                "branchFilters": [
                    "+$/<removed>"
                ],
                "timeZoneId": "W. Europe Standard Time",
                "startHours": 2,
                "startMinutes": 0,
                "daysToBuild": 31,
                "scheduleJobId": "f3bf0e7e-8cde-4d91-8e3d-63bf3e29d256",
                "scheduleOnlyWithChanges": true
            }
        ],
        "triggerType": "schedule"
    }
],
```

My problem is that when I make this change through the API there are no changes.

I `PUT` the edited JSON definition to `"${vstsBaseUrl}/build/definitions/${id}?api-version=5.0-preview.4"` (PowerShell script) and still receive a 200 OK, but my change has not been commited.

The revision number also does not increase. But the latest version of the build definition is sent as response.

Updating without a `"scheduleJobId"` does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you didn't specify the correct build definition `revision`, you need to specify the `latest revision` to update the definition.

So, you can use REST API to get the `build definition revision` first. Then use that revision in your request body to update the build definition.

[image]